# I have a question and an error. C# CS8180

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to make a basic program and here is part of my instructions:

1. Create a class "Course".

   - create a constructor with two string parameters "courseId" and "courseName".
   - create two string data members "CID" with property "ID"(set, get),  and "CName" with property "Name"(set, get).

For one, I don't understand how to have a string property "ID", when the data member already has a name, and the property is get and set.

Also, my code gives me an error code CS8180 ( { or ; or => expected ). When I click on the error, it leads me to the space after my set. Take a look:

```
using System;

class Course
{
    public string CID { get; set }

    public void CourseInfo(string courseId, string courseName)
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: `{ get; set; }`  note the Extra `;` after set. { get; set **;** }

Comment: Guyz use the typo flag.

Comment: And for your real question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property, Read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295109/9260725) of this question it will explain everyting.  CID is the underlying field behind the property ID

Comment: Thanks xdt Transform

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a ; after set :

```
using System;

class Course 
{ 
   public string CID { get; set; }

   public void CourseInfo(string courseId, string courseName)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you lema. I didn't register that that second semicolon was missing.